Rider mask implementation of a class or loop
Sometimes I can do it:

But sometimes the arrow isn't there:

This is very handy when files get a tad too large and I'm used to it in all other JetBrains product, any idea why it sometimes disappear?
Just to be clear when I click on that arrow i get:

Anyone know what could be causing that bug?

Does the issue occur randomly or after some certain actions?
What is your Rider version?
Also, could you please try clearing the caches in File | Invalidate caches => Invalidate and restart?
Will the issue reproduce after this step?

JetBrains Rider 2024.1.4 is the version I use.
It randomly occurs and restarting my computer is usually enough. I invalidated the caches but I had the problem come back an hour later. I am not able to make a MRE due to the randomness of this event.
